# Create a copy of all the redirection in my website

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-kontent, kentico-api, kentico-11

Can anyone please help me with how do I pull records or file for redirected page. I wanted to have it as a backup for my website revamp.

Comment: Is this for Kentico Xperience or Kentico Kontent?  They are two separate pieces of software, however, you've tagged both of them.   Also, if it's for Kentico Xperience, what version, as you've tagged both versions 11 and 12.

Comment: Hi @BrendenKehren thank you for the response appreciate it, let me confirm it first and get back here.